# Is it possible to execute an SQL script file using PetaPoco?

Tags: c#, sql-server, petapoco, sql-scripts

I have an SQL script file (that is, a file with a `.sql` extension) and I want to execute it using PetaPoco in C#. Is that possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I didn't tried yet because i don't know how. Using traditional c# code i can do it but using PetaPoco i don't know how...

Comment: PetaPoco is an Object-Relational-Mapping provider. Is there any Object-Relational-Mapping required to run a SQL Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file and then execute the contents:

```
string sqlstmt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\something.sql");
db.Execute(sqlstmt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Answer is no. Which you would know if you tried it. PetaPoco is an ORM - it maps relational tables to objects. Running a random SQL Script does not involve mapping tables to objects. So, your question is like asking if you can use a hammer to drive to the store.

Comment: Actually my friend i found that PetaPoco has a Execute function in the source code. I will try to extend Petapoco's Database class..

Comment: Yeah, but why use a hammer to drive to the store, when you can use a car? "Execute" is provided as an add-on, same as in the Entity Framework - but it's not the method you want to use to run random SQL Scripts. Do it the easy way!